# How to unhide Search - SmallSearchInputBox

Tags: search-box

I see following in the masterpage but the Search box dont show up next to global navigation. 
and is not hidden. visible = true too. css does not have any reference like display:none.

```
<div id="s4-searcharea" class="s4-search s4-rp">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox" Version="4"/>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <span class="s4-help">
        <span style="height:17px;width:17px;position:relative;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;" class="s4-clust">
            <a href="#" style="height:17px;width:17px;display:inline-block;" onclick="TopHelpButtonClick('HelpHome');return false"      accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplink_accesskey%>" id="TopHelpLink" title="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplinkalt_text%>" runat="server">
                <img src="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png" alt="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplinkalt_text%>" style="left:-0px !important;top:-309px !important;position:absolute;" align="absmiddle" border="0" runat="server" />
            </a>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step I'd take was to look at the page in your browsers debugging tool (F12 in IE) to see if the `<div id="s4-searcharea" ...>` contains anything else than the `<span class="s4-help">`.

If it does then the debugger tools will be able to help you find out what is hiding that content.

If there in no content then it's due to either no `<Control>` element putting anything into the `SmallSearchInputBox` DelegateControl or the `<Control>` with the highest `sequence` being empty.

To see the `<Control>` elements active at your site, and more information about `DelegateControl` and `<Control>` elements see [Checking which Delegate Controls are activated on your site](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/checking-which-delegate-controls-activated-site/)